# MS Teams integration with SVN

Tags: svn, microsoft-teams

We currently use Atlassian's Wiki software to manage our software's requirements.  Our software supports over 100 clients with a variety of customizations, so the ability to quickly "diff" two versions of specifications for a client is extremely important to do easily, and the Wiki software makes it quite easy.

Unfortunately, there is a push for us to move documentation to Microsoft Teams.  It seems like it would take a fair amount of work to look at the current document in MS Teams, and grab (usually) the previous version (or sometimes 4 versions ago, etc.), and look at the changes between the two.

I was wondering if there is an [MS Teams App](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2108436), or the possibility of coding such an app, that whenever a file was added or updated in MS Teams, the app would add/commit a copy of the document to an SVN Repository so the changes would be in a Software Configuration Management system, allowing easy version history compares.

So far, I've searched for MS Teams Apps for "Subversion" and found a couple links that talk about "Connectors" - one that [mentions Subversion](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-blog/automate-your-workflows-using-connectors-in-microsoft-teams/ba-p/113564), and another for a [GitHub connector](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104380016?src=office&tab=Overview).  Unfortunately, the connectors seem to allow other software to post notifications to an MS Teams channel.  I want MS Teams to send documents to SVN.

Now I know precious little about MS Teams, but I understand that behind the scenes it is just a "pretty" interface to SharePoint.  Is it possible to have that sort of feed?  Any examples of MS Teams Apps that do something similar?

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-flow-teams-message) help?  I think your main problem is that ***very few*** still use Subversion.  What you need to lock onto is a "trigger" mechanism.. and make that trigger do what you want, in this case.. check stuff into subversion.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; I just suggested SVN as a possibility as that is what we currently use; but we could migrate to Git if there are currently any magic for git.

Comment: To be honest.. I am going to piss a lot of people off.. git has issues too.  It is NEEDLESSLY complicated and when it doesn't do what you want.. figuring it out wastes a lot of time.  What you get with git is that MOST people are using it.  Finding someone to help you isn't difficult.  Integration into many, many applications.